# Is there any way to connect with Android Device Monitor without using usb connected

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-device-monitor

I want to track the app profiling when it is not connected with ADB(i.e its in user hand) . How can the log the information if it is not connected with Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You could either display it in a TextView in your current or another activity of your application - log in background and display, or log to a file and then view the file with another application. 
Otherwise, you could log and send your logs via a connection - i.e to a server.